# jQuery infite scrolling (duplicate items)

Tags: jquery, scroll

i'm making my new portfolio, and i have one question.
Is there a possible way to make infite scroll?
I've got somethig like this:

```
<container>
    <box></box>
    <box></box>
    <box></box>
    <box></box>
    <box></box>
    <box></box>
    <box></box>
    <box></box>
</container>
```

Is there a possibility in jQuery to make box duplicate after i reach the bottom of the container, and then show them again? So'ive got infite scroll loop?

Same thing with scrolling to the top of the container.

Comment: [Owl carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) - https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Comment: yes, but it should work on normal mousewhell scrolling

Comment: then you'd have to create something that did such a thing. that's a lot of work and you wont get that from anyone here

Comment: ok, thnx, I thought there already exist solution like that...

Comment: you could use what i said, and then wire up the mousewheel event to some of the carousel events that trigger prev/next slide. but i don't believe anything exists in the wild as a straight up plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found that very easy to achieve:

```
$('.container').bind('scroll', chk_scroll);
function chk_scroll(e) {
    var elem = $(e.currentTarget);
    if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight()) {
        $('.box').clone().insertAfter(".box:last");
    }
}
```